# How to pass dynamic arguments to docker-compose (without recreating new container IDs)?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to wrap a script in a docker container, and only be invoked with a few **dynamic** params, 1-2 times a day:
`docker-compose run example param1 param2`

While the following works as expected, the `run` command creates a new container each time the command is executed:
`docker container ls -a`

```
docker-example-run-6bfcb8ba24c8
docker-example-run-e7b7c8e8282a
docker-example-run-uja78212j1js
```

Question: how can I have a script wrapped and run it with arguments, but always reuse the same container without recreating it every time like above?

This is my code:

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  example: 
    container_name: example
    build: .
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM debian:buster-slim

COPY /scripts/example.sh /opt/app/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /opt/app/entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

`example.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Your container args are: "$@"
sleep 5 # real world process
echo finished
```

Sidenote: I know that I could use the `--rm` flag to automatically remove the container once finished. But I'd prefer creating a container without cryptic IDs, because `docker logs` also won't work out of the box on those id containers.

Comment: Is suitable for you simulate a foreground process, just to keep the container online?

Comment: If so, how can I trigger the script then with changing parameters?? I mean, afaik I cannot trigger a script inside a container again and again with different params, while the container is running, right?

Comment: A running container is like a new linux machine. If it is running, you could enter and do whatever you need or call a bash script directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your actual problem is that your logging infrastructure collects the container name, and the *name* is different between different invocations of your script.

If that's the case, [`docker-compose run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_run/) takes a `--name` option to directly set the container name

```bash
docker-compose run \
  --name docker-example-run \
  --rm \
  example \
  param1 param2
```

The name needs to be unique across all currently existing containers, but it could reuse a name from a previously deleted container.  The container itself is not especially valuable (it just contains the script process) and in this example I've used `docker-compose run --rm` to clean up the container once it's finished.